# Why is print() going to change the output of my function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a function that tries to give me the top answers of a column. In the example below there is just a part of my whole function. My final goal is to run the function over a loop. I have detected something weird: why is print(df_col_indicator) gonna change the result when I define "df_col_indicator" externally and not within my function? With print(df_col_indicator) my function is actually exactly doing what I want..

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

remove(list = ls())


dataframe_test <- data.frame(
  county_name = c("a", "b","c", "d","e", "f", "g", "h"),
  column_test1 = c(100,100,100,100,100,100,50,50),
  column_test2 = c(40,90,50,40,40,100,13,14),
  column_test3 = c(100,90,50,40,30,40,100,50),
  month = c("2020-09-01", "2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-08-01","2020-08-01"))


choose_top_5 <- function(df, df_col_indicator, df_col_month, char_month, numb_top, df_col_county) {
  
  ### this here changes output of my function
  #print(df_col_indicator) # changes output of my function depending on included or excluded
  
  ### enquo / ensym / deparse
  df_col_indicator_ensym <- ensym(df_col_indicator)
  
  df_col_month_ensym <- ensym(df_col_month)
  
  
  ### filter month and top 5 observations
  df_top <- df %>%
    filter(!!df_col_month_ensym == char_month) %>%
    slice_max(!!df_col_indicator_ensym, n = numb_top) %>%
    select(!!df_col_county, !!df_col_month_ensym, !!df_col_indicator_ensym)
  
  
  
  return(df_top)
  
  
}




### define "df_col_indicator" within the function
a = choose_top_5(df = dataframe_test, df_col_indicator = "column_test3",
                 df_col_month = "month", char_month = "2020-09-01", numb_top = 5,
                 df_col_county = "county_name")

a


### define "df_col_indicator" externally
external = "column_test3"

b = choose_top_5(df = dataframe_test, df_col_indicator = external,
                 df_col_month = "month", char_month = "2020-09-01", numb_top = 5,
                 df_col_county = "county_name")
b



### goal is to run function over loop
external <- c("column_test1","column_test2","column_test3")

my_list <- list()

for (i in external) {
  
  my_list[[i]] <- choose_top_5(df = dataframe_test, df_col_indicator = i,
                               df_col_month = "month", char_month = "2020-09-01", numb_top = 5,
                               df_col_county = "county_name")
}

my_list
```

Answer (score 4):

Your example is quite lengthy. Let's boil it down to a minimal reproducible example with two very similar functions. These both take a single argument and simply print the passed variable to the console, and return the result of calling `ensym` on the same variable.

The only difference between the two is the order in which the calls to `print` and `ensym` are made.

```r
library(rlang)

test_ensym1 <- function(x)
{
  result <- ensym(x)
  print(x)
  return(result)
}

test_ensym2 <- function(x)
{
  print(x)
  result <- ensym(x)
  return(result)
}
```

Now we might expect these two functions to do exactly the same thing, and indeed when we pass a string directly to them, they both give the same result:

```
test_ensym1("hello")
#> [1] "hello"
#> hello

test_ensym2("hello")
#> [1] "hello"
#> hello
```

But look what happens when we use an external variable to pass in our string:

```
y <- "hello"

test_ensym1(y)
#> [1] "hello"
#> y

test_ensym2(y)
#> [1] "hello"
#> hello
```

The functions both still print "hello", as expected, but they return a different result. When we called `ensym` first, the function returned the symbol `y`, and when we called `print` first it returned the symbol `hello`.

The reason for this is that when you call a function in R, the symbols you pass as parameters are not evaluated immediately. Instead, they are interpreted as *promise objects* and evaluated *as required* in the body of the function. It is this *lazy evalutation* that allows for some of the tidyverse trickery.

The difference between the two functions above is that calling `print(x)` forces the evaluation of `x`. Before that point, `x` is an unevaluated symbol. Afterwards, it behaves just like any other variable you would use interactively in the console, so when you call `ensym`, you are calling it on this evaluated variable, not as an unevaluated promise.

`ensym`, on the other hand, does *not* evaluate `x`, so if `ensym` is called first, it will return the unevaluated *symbol* that was passed to the function.

So actually, the easiest way to fix your problem is to move `print` to *after* the `ensym` call.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to change `ensym` to `as.symbol`.

Consider a function like this

```
f <- function(x) ensym(x)
myvar <- "some string"
```

You will find that

```
> f("some string")
`some string`

> f(myvar)
myvar
```

This is because `ensym` only searches for the thing **one step ahead**. It attempts to convert whatever thing found into a symbol and just returns that (note that if what found is neither a string nor variable, then you will get an error). As such, in your first example, `ensym` returns `column_test3`; in your second one, it returns `external`.

As far as I can tell, what you want to do is getting the value that `df_col_indicator` represents and then converting that value into a symbol. This means you have to first evaluate `df_col_indicator` and then convert. `as.symbol` does what you need.

```
g <- function(x) as.symbol(x)
myvar <- "some string"
```

Some tests

```
> g("some string")
`some string`

> g(myvar)
`some string`
```

Comment: Nice to see a slightly different take on it. +1

Comment: Thanks. Kudos to your answer. I didn't even consider that `print(df_col_indicator)` as OP had commented that line out. @AllanCameron